# make a variable the text inside a cell

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am sending emails from a spreadsheet. I want the value of B2 to be the body of the email. This way I can type into cell B2 what I want to say in the message. I have the script set to send the charts and data contained in the sheet, and that works. But when I tried to set the body of the email as the value of cell B2, it simply sends a message that says "Range" and then adds the charts.

My code looks like this thus far

```
function emailParentsUpdates(sheet,emails,emailSubject){
  var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = targetspreadsheet.getActiveSheet();  
  var emailSubject = 'Grades Update';
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var teacherEmail = "efazekas@dcsdk12.org"

    if(charts.length==0){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: teacherEmail,
      subject: "ERROR:"+emailSubject,
      htmlBody: "No charts in the spreadsheet"});    
      return;
    }   

    var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length);
    //this is where the issue is. I need the email body to be the value, the actual words, of cell B2
    var emailBody = sheet.getRange('B2'); 
    var emailImages={};
    for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
      var builder = charts[i].modify();
      builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
      var newchart = builder.build();
      chartBlobs[i]= newchart.getAs('image/png');
      emailBody= emailBody + "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+i+"'></p>";
      emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: emailSubject,
      htmlBody: emailBody,
      inlineImages:emailImages
    });
  }
}
```

I know it's rough and maybe not very succinct or elegant, but it does what I need except for the whole email body issue.

Comment: Post your code here.From the initial impression, solution would be you'll have to get the value of the range

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getB2Value(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B2');
  return range.getValue();
}
```

[`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) returns a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), you need to call [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) to get a reference to the value of the cell. I.e:

```
var emailBody = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to put it in the code so that the variable emailBody can be equal to the value of B2. Hopefully my code makes sense -ish.

Comment: @LizFazekas I have updated my answer to make a bit more clear.